# how to test HELO/EHLO email error with Gmail using sSMTP?

Tags: ubuntu, email, telnet, ssmtp, gmail

As SSMTP [doesn't run as a daemon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/574816/101935) per se, [how do you test](https://havetheknowhow.com/configure-the-server/install-ssmtp/) that it's working?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ telnet mordor.saundersconsulting.tech 25
Trying 127.0.1.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ swaks --to root@saundersconsulting.tech --from nicholas@saundersconsulting.tech --server mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
=== Trying mordor.saundersconsulting.tech:25...
*** Error connecting to mordor.saundersconsulting.tech:25:
***     IO::Socket::INET6: connect: Connection refused
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo cat /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
[sudo] password for nicholas: 
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=saunders.nicholas@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com

mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

AuthUser=saunders.nicholas@gmail.com
AuthPass=fdsfdsfdsf
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES


# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=

rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname
#hostname=mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
hostname=saunders.nicholas@gmail.com

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address

FromLineOverride=YES
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo cat /etc/ssmtp/revaliases
# sSMTP aliases
# 
# Format:   local_account:outgoing_address:mailhub
#
# Example: root:your_login@your.domain:mailhub.your.domain[:port]
# where [:port] is an optional port number that defaults to 25.


root:saunders.nicholas@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Not sure what to test in this scenario.

Trying the command directly yields:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ssmtp saunders.nicholas@gmail.com
to:saunders.nicholas@gmail.com
from:saunders.nicholas@gmail.com
subject:ping
testingssmtp: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

The /var/log/mail.err log shows a link to:

> HELO/EHLO email error
>
> If you tried to send an email and got back a bounce message that said
> something like "HELO/EHLO argument invalid" here are the steps you can
> take:
>
> ```
> Contact your email administrator. You should have an administrator if you’re using Gmail for a work, school, or organization account.
> ```
>
> Otherwise, you can contact your email provider.
> Ask your administrator to send the fully-qualified domain name or IP address of the sending server when contacting Gmail servers.
>
> This error usually comes up with devices like printers, scanners, and
> fax machines that also send mail.

as so:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ cat /var/log/mail.err
2023-12-19T09:37:13.183560+00:00 mordor sSMTP[11658]: Invalid response: 501 5.5.4  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo s17-20020a170902b19100b001d366f8cfd7sm7380648plr.182 - gsmtp (saunders.nicholas@gmail.com)
2023-12-19T09:37:13.184272+00:00 mordor sSMTP[11658]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
2023-12-19T13:10:01.378049+00:00 mordor sSMTP[14174]: Invalid response: 501 5.5.4  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo y20-20020a056a00191400b00688435a9915sm20054254pfi.189 - gsmtp (saunders.nicholas@gmail.com)
2023-12-19T13:10:01.378702+00:00 mordor sSMTP[14174]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
2023-12-19T13:10:36.241185+00:00 mordor sSMTP[14186]: Invalid response: 501 5.5.4  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo b18-20020a170902d51200b001cf511aa772sm20973353plg.145 - gsmtp (saunders.nicholas@gmail.com)
2023-12-19T13:10:36.241851+00:00 mordor sSMTP[14186]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
2023-12-19T13:11:49.694632+00:00 mordor sSMTP[14213]: Invalid response: 501 5.5.4  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo l15-20020a170902f68f00b001c9c5a1b477sm21000470plg.169 - gsmtp (saunders.nicholas@gmail.com)
2023-12-19T13:11:49.695296+00:00 mordor sSMTP[14213]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
nicholas@mordor:~$
```