# Are e-mails to localhost logged with sSMTP?

Tags: ubuntu, logs, email, telnet, ssmtp

I don't suppose that sSMTP will work for just sending mail on the localhost?

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo cat /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=postmaster

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=mail

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=

# The full hostname
hostname=mordor.saundersconsulting.tech

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
#FromLineOverride=YES
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo cat /etc/ssmtp/revaliases
# sSMTP aliases
# 
# Format:   local_account:outgoing_address:mailhub
#
# Example: root:your_login@your.domain:mailhub.your.domain[:port]
# where [:port] is an optional port number that defaults to 25.
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ swaks --to root@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech --from nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech --server mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
=== Trying mordor.saundersconsulting.tech:25...
*** Error connecting to mordor.saundersconsulting.tech:25:
***     IO::Socket::INET6: connect: Connection refused
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ hostname
mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

There's no mention of anything except for gmail in mail.log and mail.err which were attempted previously.  [To my understanding sSMTP only will relay e-mail.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/765165/101935)

notable result:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ssmtp nicholas@mordor.saundersconsulting.tech
subject:ping

ssmtp: Cannot open mail:25
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

that sSMTP cannot open port 25?

Answer (score 1):

From description of linux/debian `ssmtp`package:

> Package: ssmtp
> …
>
> Description-en: extremely simple MTA to get mail off the system to a mail hub
> A secure, effective and simple way of getting mail off a system to your
> mail hub. It contains no suid-binaries or other dangerous things - no mail
> spool to poke around in, and no daemons running in the background. Mail is
> simply forwarded to the configured mailhost. Extremely easy configuration.
> .
> **WARNING: the above is all it does; it does not receive mail, expand aliases
> or manage a queue. That belongs on a mail hub with a system administrator.**